# IOS accessibility: Turn page in iBooks with headphone buttons / bluetooth keyboard?

Tags: ipad, books, accessibility

I am trying to help someone with disabilities to turn pages in e.g. iBooks on the iPad. All I need for this is a single button, possibly one that iOS can interpret as an accessibility switch.

I have looked at bluetooth switches that are made for this purpose, but it always seems like I have to purchase at least two devices (that amount to the equivalent of about USD 200) even in this simple use case. We're not aiming to control the whole OS, just to turn pages.

Is there no way to just use $10 earphone controls as a switch instead? Jailbreak or not.

Or can pages be turned in iBooks with a paired Bluetooth keyboard? That would be great.

Comment: Try holding down the command button while in iBooks; if a dialog pops up there are shortcuts, otherwise nope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the hard way (went to a store) that you **can** use arrow keys on a Bluetooth keyboard to change pages in ePubs, but not in PDFs. At least in iBooks.

The problem now is that it doesn't work in apps that can read Adobe copy protected ePubs.

Comment: Could you please explain how you can use the arrow keys? I've tried everything with my bluetooth keyboard, and can't get this to work. iBooks with iOS 7.1. Thanks!

Comment: I have tried it on iOS 9 — iBooks is bundled with iOS. IOS 7.1 is over two years old which is a very long time in software. I can only recommend an update.

Answer (score -1):

The e-reader app Marvin has a feature that let you turn pages using the arrow keys on a Bluetooth keyboard :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide **supporting info** as to why they're the best.  Answers should be self-contained so explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links as supporting information can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer.